# laravel 5.1 access package config values

Tags: php, laravel

I'm starting a package on laravel 5.1. Up till now using laravel 4.2

I've been able to publish the package config file using the following in the `boot` method of the service provider for my package as described in the documents:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__ . '/config/config.php' =>   config_path('/packages/longestdrive/googlecal/googlecal.php'),
    ]);
```

Now I'm trying to access the items in this config using:

```
config('googlecal.client_id');
```

This however returns `null`

If I simply do: `config()` I get a full array of the config arrays and can see my package config file there.

If I then do: `config('longestdrive.googlecal.googlecal.client_id')` I can access the variable.

In L4.2 I did not need to add effectively the full path to the variable.

Have I missed something to enable me to simply do: `config('googlecal.client_id')`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to merge your config file in ServiceProvider

```
/**
 * Register the service provider.
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('laravel-db-localization', function ($app) {
        return new LaravelDbLocalization();
    });

    // Load the config file
    $this->mergeConfigFrom(__DIR__.'/config/laravel-db-localization.php', 'laravel-db-localization');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should run "php artisan config:cache", it works for me:)